# Delete all user sessions or log all users out of omniauth based Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, omniauth

I have some changes in the Rails app because of which I would like to log all users out of my rails app so that they have to log back in and a new procedure runs. I am using omniauth. This is how I store the user sessions:

```
require 'action_dispatch/middleware/session/dalli_store'
App::Application.config.session_store  :dalli_store, :memcache_server => ['127.0.0.1:11211'], :key => '_session', :expire_after => 14.days
```

I tried changing the key name for session store but that did not work. I am not sure what other details are needed, so please ask for the relevant code in the comments.

Comment: I belive removing all session from storage should work (which equals to clearing whole memcache, unless you keep something else there)

Comment: I keep other things in the memcached. Is there any alternative to clearing the memcache?

Comment: Ok, but those other things can get recreated (like fragment caches, object caches, etc). Other solution would be to, upon user coming back, check if session was created before you rolled out the changes and `reset_session`.

Comment: Hello Varun did you solve this problem. Its happening with Omniauth Facebook and Twitter gem also.